# Force Spring to use a specific class in place of another one at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

My Spring app depends on a library that I need to override a class from, let's say `com.dep.A`. I want to create class `B` which extends `A`, and tell spring that every time `A` is trying to be loaded (by any code or dependency) I want to load `B` instead.

Is there a spring setting that would achieve this ? If not, would AspectJ be an option (I think Spring has an AspectJ feature) ?

EDIT: a bit more specific on the use case
If I were only able to plug myself into the execution flow of a specific method of class `A`, I'd be pretty please. In fact, forget about `B` extending `A`: what I am really trying to achieve is to intercept the execution of method `A.originalMethod(MyObject o)`, and use `o` in my custom method `B.interceptOriginalMethod()`.

Comment: Seems to me like you could just move the class A to another package and rename your class B to A, no need for super special runtime magic. That being said, are you sure this is what you want to do? Sounds like a 10 on a 0-10 scale of evil.

Comment: Unfortunately, as class A is in a dependency of my Spring (listed in the dependencies of my `pom.xml`), I cannot move that class anywhere since I don't have control of it.

Comment: Are objects of that class Spring beans? If yes it can be done at run-time (no recompilation if you use XML configuration), if no, Spring cannot help.

Comment: @J.Doe It being a dependency is not (shouldn't be) an issue. Either write a plugin that automates the changes for you, or if that's too much of a hassle just create a custom version of your dependency with your changes in it and depend on that.

Comment: This is general java problem, spring is not the framework to address this. You could produce your version of the class A (and call it A) and make sure your class is first on the classpath (or remove the original class A from the classpath at all). Needless to say, you cannot inherit from A in this scenario. May be you could achieve your wanted scenario if you had control over the classloaders of your application, but I wonder if it is worth the hassle. I found the whole scenario (slip another class to foreign code) quite scary, to say the least.

Comment: How about using aspects ? I don't really want to replace the original code, I want to plug myself into the execution flow of a specific method of class A, and carefully add a few things in the manipulated objects. Moreover, I want to get away from Spring xml configuration.

Comment: It looks like it could really be done with load-time weaving. And yes, you could set-up that with spring. I however do not have all the details at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class is from a different library, it does not sound like it is a spring bean, and then Spring can't help you. It basically comes down to how the object is constructed, if the *new* operator is not called by you, but code inside the library you only have two options (Unless the Jar is signed, then I think there are no options).

1. Load time weaving. Which allows you to insert a cutpoint and replace the code of the method. This requires starting the JVM with a java agent,  and should be a last resort.
2. If you have the source code, you can use class shadowing. You simply copy the class source into your source tree (same package name). This works because */classes* is almost always before libraries in the classpath, so when the classloader try to load the class it will find your modified version, hence shadowing the original.

I have used option 2 a couple of times to fix minor issues in different open source libraries, when I was too lazy to rebuild the entire library from source. You have to be carefully when you upgrade the library, in case they have change the underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` to load a bean by name instead of type. Below is the example

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("b")
private A a;
```

The above code will load the reference of class B, provided B is also a spring bean.

Comment: This would work if I had control on the code where class A is used. Unfortunately I don't, since it belongs to a dependency of my Spring app (listed in my pom.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Though @Klaus Groenbaek answer is correct (and I'll mark it as so), I have resolved my problem using another approach.

I was lucky enough that `com.dep.A` is annotated with Spring's [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html).

Therefore, simply create bean `B`extending `A` and in your main application class declare:

```
@Bean 
public A a(){ 
  return new A(); 
}
```

Spring will load your class instead of the original one.